# How to locally access influx db deployed on GCP kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, influxdb

Influxdb 1.8 is deployed on kubernets using helm charts. influx db is deployed as Stateful Set that exposes a service with one running pods. Am able to ssh into running pods using `kubectl exec` command and its running fine. I can also see databases using influx cli after logging into pods

But i need to access this influx db on my local system to execute queries directly from my system using curl command. Deployed influxdb has no external IP/DNS. It ha internal endpoint that usually starts with 10.*.*.*

Can anybody guide me on how can i access influxdb on my local system using curl command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`kubectl port-forward` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/). You can use it to either map a Pod or a Service TCP port to a port on your local machine:

```
> kubectl port-forward service/your-influxdb-service 8086:8086
                                                      ^    ^
                                                      |    |
                                             local port    remote/service port
```

While that command is running, `kubectl` will forward all connections to your local port `8086` to the same port of your InfluxDB service. All traffic will be funneled through kubectl and your API server, so this is not exactly suited for high-throughput scenarios, but should be sufficient for occasional debugging and testing.